# jenkins+maven ignoring git global config

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to run a maven build that utilizes frontend-maven-plugin to run bower.  Bower in turn executes git from the commandline to download the dependencies.  Our firewall blocks the git:// protocol, so I ran `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`.  However, it appears that it is ignoring it:

`[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.26:bower (bower install) @ janus ---
[INFO] Running 'bower install' in D:\Jenkins\workspace\janus
[INFO] bower bootstrap#~3.3.5      not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.3.5
[INFO] bower bootstrap#~3.3.5         resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.3.5
[ERROR] bower bootstrap#~3.3.5         ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=No error`

I've fully updated and restarted Jenkins, but no luck.  The same command executed from the commandline works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Jenkins is running on Windows under the LocalSystem account.  The "global" git config is actually per-user.

- Using psexec, run cmd as LocalService: `psexec -i -s -d CMD`
- In the cmd prompt that opens, execute `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`